# Position of Error Message Block not changed

Tags: magento-1.9, page-layouts, global-messages

I have a problem with my theme:
The error message is not at the top of the page.
[image: See error message at bottom of page]

It should be like this:

[image]

Now the real problem:
For my test environment I already found a solution, by changing the order of following code in 2columns-left.phtml from

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('index_block') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>                                        
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

TO

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>                                        
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('index_block') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

But in my live environment, there is no change! I already flushed cache, reindexed and compared the both installations (no differences in files). Compiler is not active.

The block above the error message in first pic is the cms_block "index_block".

Any ideas?

Comment: in which file you have changed add you file path

Comment: It was \app\design\frontend\default\theme259k\template\page\2columns-left.phtml.  But I found a solution will post it immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found workaround, can't tell why I didn't think of it in first place.

In my cms-page "home" I changed:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="index_block">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>index_block</block_id></action>
</block>
```

To

```
<block type="cms/block" name="index_block" after="global_messages">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>index_block</block_id></action>
</block>
```

Seems like index_block in 2columns-left.phtml is not the same as the cms-block?!

Still don't know why the change of code worked in test but not in live, but with this solution everything works fine.